# Finding the consecutive sums of an array

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working through a coding challenge.  The challenge basically wants me to find the max sum of its k consecutive elements.  Here is an example:

For `inputArray = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]` and `k = 2`, the output should be
`arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k) = 8`.
All possible sums of 2 consecutive elements are:

```
2 + 3 = 5;
3 + 5 = 8;
5 + 1 = 6;
1 + 6 = 7.
```

Thus, the answer is 8.

This is my attempt.  I looked at the consecutive sum as sub-lists.  So if I have `k=3`, then I have to add the 2 elements following i.  So if the beginning is index 0, then the end is beginning + k-1.  Then I tried to use a for loop to append the sum of every k chunks to a new list.  My end goal was to return the `max()` from this list:

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    begin = 0
    end = begin + (k-1)
    sum_list = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(inputArray)):
        begin = i
        sum_list.append(sum(inputArray[begin:end+1]))
    
    print(sum_list)
```

Now I just wanted to see what my `sum_list` looked like before I tried to return its max.  However, this is what it returns for a test case:

```
Input: inputArray: [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]
k: 2
Output: null
Expected Output: 8
Console Output: [5, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

I think my logic is correct.  I would just like to know where it is that I am making a mistake.

Comment: `end = begin + (k-1)` does not mean that end will *always* be equal to that value.  If `begin` changes, you have to change `end`, which you do not do in your loop.

Comment: check my answer that should solve your problem

Comment: Your question doesn't state anywhere that you need a better execution time AND your only question is around finding out where you are making a mistake. Please update your question incase those are part of the criteria. Also, please clear your variable memory and re-run some of the solutions because it seems you are getting different results than what others are.

Comment: Sliding window method is to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fairly efficient solution is to use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for generating groups of consecutive elements. This removes the need for slicing your list

```
consecutive_elements = zip(*(islice(inputArray, x, None) for x in range(k)))
```

An example of what the islice generator produces:

```
>>> [list(islice(range(5), x, None)) for x in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

`islice(inputArray, x, None) for x in range(k)` creates iterables from your input that slice off increasing numbers of elements, passing this to `zip` then joins the iterables element wise creating your groups

And then use `map` to generate the sums rather than creating an intermediary list

```
return max(map(sum, consecutive_elements))
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer I don't believe the grouper recipe creates repeated consecutive groups that overlap but rather splits the iterable into chunks that do not overlap

Comment: Yes, you are right. Blaming that one on a long week and Friday night...should just go to bed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something more readable and without using any other libraries such as `itertools`, you can try this one-liner -

```
[sum(i) for i in zip(*(inputArray[i:] for i in range(k)))]
```

```
[5, 8, 6, 7]
```

---

**Debugging your code :**

There are a few things wrong in the code. First, you are defining the end outside the loop. As begin change you want the end to change in the loop as well. Also, since python already considers `n-1` index for end, you just need to set it to `begin+k` and not `begin+(k-1)`. Next, you need to move the iterator from 0 to length or array - 1 as the last item will be just a single element. If you want to see where you have gone wrong, I have modified the code to run as you expect it to -

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    #begin = 0 #<--- #No need since you are setting it to i in loop
    #end = begin + k #<--- Not to be defined here but inside loop
    sum_list = []
    
    for i in range(0, len(inputArray)-1): #<----
        begin = i
        end = begin + k #<--- 
        sum_list.append(sum(inputArray[begin:end])) #<----
    
    print(sum_list)
```

```
[5, 8, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Your code outputs `[5, 8, 6, 7, 6]`.  It also does nothing about execution time

Comment: Can you check again? I am not getting the 6 at the end. Thats because i am moving my range to `len(inpArray) -1`

Comment: I can share a screenshot if that helps.

Comment: updated my solution, this doesn't use any other libraries such as `itertools`.

Comment: This creates multiple lists in memory which may perform badly given large enough input

Comment: Change `[ ]` to `( )`.This create a generator instead of a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your ending index.

```
def arrayMaxConsecutiveSum(inputArray, k):
    begin = 0
    end = begin + k
    sum_list = []

    for i in range(0, len(inputArray)):
    
        sum_list.append(sum(inputArray[i:i + k]))

    print(sum_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

take the sum from given index to index + k for (5 -(k-1)) times in this case and the max

```
inputArray = [2, 3, 5, 1, 6]
k = 3
print(max([sum(inputArray[idx : idx + k]) for idx in range(len(inputArray)-(k-1))]))
```

Comment: Adding a quick explanation with this code sample can help improve this answer.

Comment: @shinjw yes sure I have added a quick explaination